# Force FormControl change (without user intervention) to trigger Observable change with .distinctUntilChanged

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a FormControl/service that gets updated as user types input into field, as follows:

```
  term = new FormControl();
  page = new BehaviorSubject(1);
  ..
  ..
  // Call to search 
  search(this.term.valueChanges, this.page);

  // Search definition
  search(term: Observable<string>, page: BehaviorSubject<number>,  debounceDuration = 400) { 
      return term.debounceTime(debounceDuration)
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .switchMap(term => this.productSearch(term,page.getValue()));
  }
```

This works as expected, so if a user types in 'run' and a few second later 'running' it triggers a call to search each time the term is changed.

Now, elsewhere I have a separate function (part of a third party component). When this function gets called, I want to mimic as if a user changed the term to re-trigger a call to search.

```
getPage(p: number) {
    this.page.next(p);
    this.term.setValue(this.term.value + " ");
    }
```

I've only managed to get it to work by re-setting the term value with an extra space (which of course explicitly add its to the UI). I've tried some of the other options in FormControl (setDirty, setTouched), but nothing seems to trigger a change. Is there some way to set a flag without actually changing the value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge` and "merge" another Observable (Subject in this case) into the chain that calls `this.productSearch()` after the `distinctUntilChanged` operator (note that this will not update the form field):

```
private trigger$ = new Subject();

getPage(p: number) {
    this.trigger$.next(this.term.value);
}

search(.....) { 
    return term.debounceTime(debounceDuration)
       .distinctUntilChanged()
       .merge(this.trigger$)
       .switchMap(term => this.productSearch(term,page));
}
```

Comment: Tried this but getting: Property 'merge' does not exist on type 'Observable<string>'. Updating the method signatures to see if the call/error makes more sense.I 'm going to try and create an Observable.

Comment: You have to import it first with ‘import “rxjs/add/operator/merge”’

Comment: Thanks. I did have to merge import. Your merge() suggestion pointed me in the right direction and I ended up using combineLatest with an explicit Observable to watch both terms. It worked as expected for me with "return Observable.combineLatest(term,page.asObservable()).debounceTime(debounceDuration).distinctUntilChanged().... "